# Can we use Artifactory to store iOS builds for OTA installation?

Tags: ios, artifactory, cicd, ota

Apple supports Over The Air (OTA) installation as long as we store both the manifest and the IPA in a publicly accessible location. Then we only have to share the URL of the manifest with our stake holders. I'm trying to store iOS builds in an Artifactory repository (generic package type) and achieve the same.

Currently we are storing them in our intranet and the setup works fine. We are looking at migrating to Artifactory but so far we have been unsuccessful even with anonymous access enabled (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Users+and+Groups).

I reached out to JFrog. They only said it is possible but haven't offered any help. The license I have is basic and it doesn't cover SLA level support.

Answer (score 0):

We need more informations

Are you able to download the IPA and the manifest with curl?

Be sure that you are using the 'List Browsing'

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Browsing+Artifacts

Comment: When I run curl mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/ios-builds/my-branch/MyApp.ipa nothing gets downloaded. If I disable anonymous access then I see a 401. If you can confirm that list browsing is the solution I will mark your answer as correct. I don't have access to the artifactory anymore as the company abandoned it.